# Unable to connect to Mysql Database hosted on VM Windows Server using 3306 port

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, remote-server

I have been trying to find a solution but could not fixed my problem. MySQL database is hosted on a remote server inside Virtual Machine, I have only rights to the Virtal Machne, I have tried following solutions but still my problem is not fixed: Added 3306 port for MYSQL in firewall settings, disabled the firewall, remove bind-address from my.ini files on my local machine as well as server and grant the priviliges from mysql client tool but no success. Can anyone help me out with this problem please?

[image: Connection Error]

Comment: Is mysql on you VM configured to listen on external ip?

Comment: I am using 206.196.97.XXX to connect to the mysql database